# What are the possible downsides for Puerto Ricans if Puerto Rico becomes a state?

Tags: united-states, statehood, puerto-rico

My impression from reading about **Puerto Rican views** on statehood is that besides the pro-statehood and the pro-independence camp, there also is significant support for the status quo. Of course, some of this support might be come from those who consider their preferred goal unattainable, and don't want to waste resources on pursuing something unachievable. But I am still wondering whether there are downsides for Puerto Rico from their standpoint to becoming a US State, other than this making independence much harder to achieve?

Some background reading (thanks Jontia): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_quo_movement_in_Puerto_Rico

For example, in the 2012 referendum 46% voted for keeping the status quo.

Comment: Who is trying to prevent their independence? This is all about changing the balance in the senate and the electoral college.

Comment: @JoeW I am asking about the Puerto Rican perspective, not the mainland US perspective. If you are claiming that wanting to keep the balance for senate/house/electorial college unchanged is a significant reason for Puerto Ricans to oppose Puerto Rican statehood, please find some sources and post that as an answer.

Comment: @JoeW the question doesn't ask for anything related to wider US politics, but about support for the status quo in PR. Seems well supported, but this wiki page at least doesn't say why. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_quo_movement_in_Puerto_Rico#:~:text=In%20the%20Puerto%20Rican%20status,successful%20referendum%20for%20statehood%20advocates.

Comment: That is not what I got from the question. To me it is reading as including everything. You should clarify as asking from that side. You should also include other referendums as the one in 2017 got 97.13% voting for statehood. Sure there is controversy surrounding it but it is still an important data point.

Comment: @JoeW Neither the 2017 nor the 2020 referendum seem to be particular relevant here. The former was widely boycotted, and the latter just asked about statehood yes/no - and thus doesnt let us distinguish between the independence and the status quo camps. But the 2021 referendum clearly shows that there is a status quo camp in the first place.

Comment: There was still a lot of polling done around the 2017 one that indicated that statehood was the majority preference. The numbers I saw had it at just over 50%. I find it hard to ignore that a vote actually occurred and what the results where. It is very problematic to just try and ignore different elections that happened. Also I am not sure what it matters how many people support an option or not as that won't change the upsides and downsides of doing that option.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't accurately reflect the body, and people will respond to the title without reading the body, because that's what humans do. You may want to clarify the title.

Comment: @JoeW You seem to be reading something into my question that is not there. 1. There seems to be a sizable number of Puerto Ricans who prefer the status quo over both Statehood and independence. 2. It seems quite plausible that this is because they perceive downsides to statehood other than making independence harder. 3. I don't know what these downsides are. I want to know. So I ask.

Comment: @barbecue What difference do you see there? Do you have a suggestion for a title that would better reflect question text?

Comment: I am just saying you can't ignore the results of some referendums and the polls around them just because you don't like them. I am also saying that the number of supporters on  each side of the issue don't matter as the pros and cons of it won't change. For your example it doesn't matter if 10% or 90% support status quo for the purposes of asking if gaining independence after becoming a state is harder or not. I did a quick google search and found several articles listing 5-10 different points on both sides about the pros/cons of becoming a state none of which cared about support numbers.

Comment: I think it would be better to remove the points about who on the island supports what and focus on what would be the downsides of them becoming a state.

Comment: @arno There have been several edits, but the one that said "What are the possible downsides to Puerto Rican statehood for Puerto Ricans?" was the clearest in my opinion. I'd recommend making it even clearer by saying "What are the possible downsides for Puerto Ricans if Puerto Rico becomes a state?" I'm assuming you want to know about negative effects on the people, rather than negative effects on the legal status of the territory.

Comment: @barbecue Your suggestion fits, even it is a slightly long for my taste. Anyway, I'll go with it.

Comment: @divibisan Thanks for the suggestion, but that is not the question I am after.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The only two certainties in life are death and taxes.**

While Puerto Ricans do pay some federal taxes such as FICA (Social Security), for the most part, Puerto Ricans currently do not pay federal income taxes. Becoming a state would immediately subject all Puerto Ricans to the federal income tax. There would most likely be enhanced benefits to Puerto Rico should it become a state, but this is not a certainty. Being subject to federal income tax would be an absolute certainty.

**¿Habla Inglés?**

Despite the fact that the US does not have an official language, there would be huge pressure on Puerto Rico to make English be its dominate language should it become a state. This would likely result in a reduction of their Hispanic heritage and culture. Puerto Ricans are very proud of their culture, which is older than that of the US.

Comment: I did not mean "Habla Inglés"' to be taken derogatorily. I know what "haluatko kupin kahvia" (Finnish) and "vil du ha en kopp kaffe" (Norwegian) mean ("would you like a cup of coffee"), but that is about the extent of my cultural heritage. Other than remembering a few key phrases, knowing how to make weird holiday breads, and being able to roll naked in a snowbank after a sauna, my cultural heritage has been wiped out.

Comment: For the first point there is a closely connected question that goes into detail as to how much purto rico receives from the government vs how much it pays in taxes.  Put simply PR is currently getting far more out of the government then they are paying in, and so statehood likely would result in a much higher tax burden with any additional financial support from the federal government unlikely to compensate for the increased taxes: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25501/are-us-territories-getting-the-same-degree-of-federal-support-without-paying-as

Answer (score 4):

The language barrier there isn't merely an inconvenience. [The English-Spanish debate has been contentious there before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language_in_Puerto_Rico)

> In 1991 the government of Puerto Rico, under the administration of PPD's Rafael Hernández Colón, made Spanish its sole official language through a law that was commonly called the "Spanish-only Law." In recognition of the historical defense of the Spanish language and culture, the Spanish Monarchy awarded Puerto Rico the Principe de Asturias' Prize that same year. On 4 January 1993, the 12th Legislative Assembly, with the support of the newly elected PNP government of Pedro Rosselló González passed Senate Bill 1, establishing both Spanish and English as official languages of the government of Puerto Rico.

> In 2009, the grassroots community cultural organization Unidos por Nuestro Idioma ("United for our language"), whose goal is "defending Spanish in Puerto Rico", expressed concern that the use of English terms on official road signs reading "Welcome to Guaynabo City", and on mass transit ("City Hall" and "Downtown") as well as police cruisers ("San Juan Police Department") were evidence of the English language replacing Spanish in official use. The group advocates the defense and use of Spanish in Puerto Rico. The group states it is not against the use of English, recognizing the importance of Puerto Ricans learning it, but states that it should not displace Spanish.

This would be the first state where English was not the predominant language of its population. [The 2000 census found very few people there speak English](https://welcome.topuertorico.org/culture/language.shtml)

> Both Spanish and English are the official languages of Puerto Rico, but Spanish is without a doubt the dominant language, as the majority of the people in Puerto Rico are not proficient in English. Fewer than 20 percent of Puerto Ricans speak English fluently, according to the 2000 U.S. Census.

Hawaii, by contrast, [had been forced by the US government to switch long before it became a state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_language) so it never really became as large an issue. There would be increased pressure to have more English taught and used.

Comment: Is this a general "more integration into the US will strenghten English compared to Spanish" issue, or are there concrete mechanisms how the federal government could make Puerto Rico use English?

Comment: @Arno It's more a general integration problem. The vast majority of the US uses English, and being a state would increase the need for English, far more than what it is now. There are some nativist Puerto Ricans, and they would likely oppose such efforts. It's unlikely (given the current political climate) that they would be forced to switch by the Federal government.

Comment: @Arno: Canada & Quebec make an interesting parallel to this (right down to people complaining about signage!)  Basically, in the early 20th century English was the language of the moneyed elites while French was the language of the poorer working class.  This led to several acts (most notably the [Charter of the French Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charter_of_the_French_Language)) that sought to protect French as the primary language of Quebec.  It's not too hard for me to imagine a similar situation playing out in Puerto Rico should they gain statehood.